# AngularJs - Change/Push select color from controller with a $parent ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a very simple example:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hh2R/29/)

Here is the MainCtrl

```
function MainCtrl($scope)
   {
   $scope.color = {};
   $scope.colors = [
       { name: "red" },
       { name: "yellow" },
   ];

 var newColor = $scope.color;
    newColor.name = "blue";  
$scope.colors.push(newColor);
$scope.selectedColor = newColor;
```

}

**I have 3 html forms:**

1. MainForm.Html
2. AvailableColors.html (partial, embeded on MainForm.html with ng-include)
3. AddNewColor.html

**MainForm.Html looks like this:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div ng-include="'AvailableColors.html'">
</div>
```

**AvailableColors.html looks like this:**

```
<select ng-model="$parent.selectedColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
  <option value="" selected>Select Color ..</option>  
</select>
<a href="#">Add New Color</a>
<br />
value is {{ selectedColor }}
```

In the JsFiddle example, I am trying to simulate the user adding a new color. I need the AvailableColors' ng-model to have '$parent.' as it comes from an ng-include, and w/o '$parent', chosen selections will not be in scope on form submit.

**My problem is I cannot push the newly added color to AvailableColors.html when the user adds them.**

Any ideas?

One note: I know in the JsFiddle the new color 'blue' is added, but that's because there really is no ng-include in that example.

Evidently, when there actually is a ng-include, it does not appear, short of refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

The parent is read only from children. To do what you want, you will have to use methods like those in your parent controller.

```
    $scope.setSelected = function(color) {
        $scope.selectedColor = color;
    }

    $scope.addColor = function(newColor) {
       $scope.colors.push(newColor);
    }
```

Then, you can use input like those in your included html :

```
//Selector
<select ng-click="setSelected(selectColor)" ng-model="selectColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
  <option value="" selected>Select Color ..</option>
</select>

//Add control
<input type="text" ng-model="newColor.name" />
<button id="addBtn" ng-click="addColor(newColor)">Add</button>
```

As you can see, I added a ng-click on the select to update the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use reference to objects on your $scope ([as recommended by the Angular team](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m)), you will not have to use `$parent` anywhere:

```js
$scope.model = {selectedColor: ''};  // use an object here
$scope.addColor = function(newColorName) {
  $scope.colors.push({name: newColorName});
};
```

AvailableColors.html:

```html
<select ng-model="model.selectedColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
   <option value="" selected>Select Color ..</option>  
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="colorName">
<button ng-click="addColor(colorName); colorName=''">Add</button>
<br />
value is {{ model.selectedColor }}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/shR2tmcsTph7eOt1FbDj?p=preview), which uses ng-include.